# How do i let a android webview print or share the page to my printer?

Tags: android, printing, webview

I have a android app with webview that displays a internet webpage, i made a fully php website that is optimized for a android app with webview.

The app does nothing more than displaying that website, i have a webpage that i want to print with the android app, what do i need to do to make that work ?

Or a share button/bar where i can click on print same as chrome browser does on phone.

Main activity android studio:

```kotlin
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.*******/");

        mywebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    }

    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
    }
}
```